# ProblemwithfindTextBoxinASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, panel

i have the problem, that i create a TextBox via vb.net Code while the programm ist running.

```
    Private Sub GenerateTBSourcePath()
    'Generiert eine neue leere Textbox
    Dim tBox As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox()
    tBox.Width = 400
    Dim tbID As Integer = tbSourcePathID + 1
    tBox.ID = "tbSourcePath_" + tbID.ToString()
    pSourcePath.Controls.Add(tBox)
End Sub
```

When i try to search for the TextBox on pSourcePath i cant find any TextBox.
Have anyone an idea what do i wrong?

i add the TextBox in start of my programm. I can see the TextBox also in the Browser. When i want to save the Text i cant find the TextBox.

```
Private Sub SaveTBox()
    'Für jede TBox den Eintrag in der DB aktualisieren oder einen neuen Eintrag anlegen
    For Each PControl As System.Web.UI.Control In pSourcePath.Controls
        Dim Controltype As String = PControl.GetType().FullName
        Select Case Controltype
            Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"
                Dim tBox As WebControls.TextBox = CType(PControl, WebControls.TextBox)
                If CheckExists(tBox.ID) = True
                    'Update
                    Administration_DataSource.UpdateCommand = "Update di_source set PATH = '" & tBox.Text & "' where TBID = '" & tBox.ID & "'"
                    Administration_DataSource.Update()
                Else
                    'Insert
                    tbSourcePathID = tbSourcePathID + 1
                    Administration_DataSource.InsertCommand = "Insert Into di_source(ID, PATH, TBID) values('" & tbSourcePathID & "', '" & tBox.Text & "', '" & tBox.ID & "')"
                    Administration_DataSource.Insert()
                End If
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thereisareasontheformdidntwantyoutouseprobleminyourtitle

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code

```
int tbSourcePathID = 0;
TextBox tBox = new TextBox();
PlaceHolder pSourcePath = new PlaceHolder();
tBox.Width = 400;
int tbID = tbSourcePathID + 1;
tBox.ID = "tbSourcePath_" + tbID.ToString();
pSourcePath.Controls.Add(tBox);

foreach (System.Web.UI.Control PControl in pSourcePath.Controls)
{
   string Controltype = PControl.GetType().FullName;
   switch (Controltype)
   {
     case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox":
          bool here = true;
          break;
   }
}
```

and it works. Maybe the problem is in CheckExists(). Remember also the use of FindControl()